# Right Alt key also triggers Windows Message for Left Control key

Tags: winapi, keyboard-events

In a win32 message handler I'd like to be able to handle Left and Right Alt and Control keys. Left and Right is distinguished with bit 24 of lParam, but when I press the Right Alt then I also get a message for Left Control key (Right Alt is therefore "alt gr"). Is there a way to switch off this behavior or somehow distinguish the message for the Left Control key that was triggered by the Right Alt key?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this issue and found that Keyboard Language had **United States-International keyboard** selected. Switching that fixed the issue.

[image: Image of keyboard language]

I figured it out thanks to [Dell - Right Alt click does not work](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-au/000136390/right-alt-click-does-not-work-in-windows-7)

Answer (score -1):

Read about reading the keyboard states using [Msdn GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Then call `GetKeyState()` and use the `VK` of `VK_LSHIFT` `VK_RSHIFT` `VK_LCONTROL` `VK_RCONTROL` `VK_LMENU` `VK_RMENU` to see if it is pressed or not.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, i.e. if I press right alt then GetKeyState() reports that VK_CONTROL and VK_LCONTROL are down

Comment: In that case you may have to determine the keyboard layout and detect that the left alt key is mapped to the control key, or something like that.